# php mb_strtolower doesn't work as intended on some UTF-8 non ascii chars

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

mb_strtolower() doesn't produce the intended result for some cases, such as in some Greek Polytonic letters, for example in the following string `ᾬγαθός`, you can see how it should become in the javascript version below.

PHP (up to 7.1.1):

```
$s = "Łukasz Åland Ἡράκλειον ᾬγαθός Ὕλλον";
echo $s . "<br>";
echo mb_strtolower($s, "UTF-8");
```

output:

```
Łukasz Åland Ἡράκλειον ᾬγαθός Ὕλλον
łukasz åland ἡράκλειον ᾬγαθός ὕλλον
```

(Correct)
javascript:

```
"Łukasz Åland Ἡράκλειον ᾬγαθός Ὕλλον".toLowerCase()
```

output:

```
łukasz åland ἡράκλειον ᾤγαθός ὕλλον
```

Is there something I can do, or is this a bug?

Comment: @Samir that link is irrelevant, I'm talking about PHP, not javascript.

Comment: Did you already check if it also happens in PHP 7.2?

Comment: @jasie I didn't have that installed, will check now.

Comment: Good, let us know.

Comment: @jasie it works OK in 7.2.4, thanks for the tip. It's a non problem.

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a non issue, the problem does not appear in php 7.2.4 and higher.